# Any quicker method to find matrix exponent for a scaled permutation matrix?

Tags: matrices

I am trying to find the eigen value of matrix $e^A$ such that the matrix A is given as

$$ 
\begin{bmatrix}
a & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & a\\
0 & a & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I found $A^2 = \begin{bmatrix} a^2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & a^2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & a^2 \end{bmatrix}$, $A^3 = \begin{bmatrix} a^3 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & a^3 \\ 0 & a^3 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ and so forth...

So that I can find, $e^A$ by substituting above matrices in its power series expansion
\begin{equation}
e^A = 1 + A + \frac{1}{2!} A^2+\dots 
\end{equation}

which gives

\begin{equation}
e^A =
\begin{bmatrix}
1+a+\frac{1}{2}a^2+\frac{1}{6}a^3+\dots & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1+\frac{1}{2}a^2+\frac{1}{24}a^4+\dots & a+\frac{1}{6}a^3+\frac{1}{120}a^5\dots \\
0 & a+\frac{1}{6}a^3+\frac{1}{120}a^5\dots & 1+\frac{1}{2}a^2+\frac{1}{24}a^4+\dots
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

which can be written as

\begin{equation}
e^A =
\begin{bmatrix}
e^a & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \frac{e^a}{2}+\frac{e^{-a}}{2} & \frac{e^a}{2}-\frac{e^{-a}}{2} \\
0 & \frac{e^a}{2}-\frac{e^{-a}}{2} & \frac{e^a}{2}+\frac{e^{-a}}{2}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

I am able to solve this, but I am wondering if there is a quicker way or a trick that I can use to find $e^A$ quickly that this method?

Comment: One thing you can do as well is to note that your matrix is diagonalisable. The exponential of a diagonal matrix is very simple.

Comment: Please avoid double dollar signs or displays on titles. Regards,

Comment: Your matrix exponent $A$ is real symmetric, so it has a complete basis of eigenvalues, i.e. $A$ is diagonalizsble.  If you are interested in the eigenvalues of  $e^A$, you should work with the eigenvalues of $A$.

Answer (score 2):

By diagonalization,
$$\exp\begin{pmatrix} 0 & a \\ a & 0 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \cosh(a) & \sinh(a) \\ \sinh(a) & \cosh(a)\end{pmatrix} $$
is just De Moivre/Euler's formula $e^{i\alpha}=\cos(\alpha)+i\sin(\alpha)$ written in a equivalent way.